# Different User types with separate session in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am developing a cakephp 3 application, where there would be more than one type of users, eg: I have three different sets of users
1- Customers
2- Administrators
3- Vendors

The basic requirement is that i want these session to be different from each other, suppose if on a browser i am logged in as customer using my customer login credential, i should not be able to use the same session to get into the administrators part of my website, i tried to use the admin prefix routing but it is using a single session like if i am logged in as customer i am also able to access the administrators, vendors part too.

I have done little search and found that every cakephp application has default session and for separating these session one should create there different cakephp application, would that be a wise decision or is there a way around using a single cakephp application, please help and suggest.

Comment: I don't understand why you want "different sessions", there is simple thing called [authorization](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#authorization) in CakePHP, and it is all explained in [the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what).

Comment: Actually, I have three different users tables 1-customers 2-administrators 3-vendors with different fields. and i dont want to use a single users table for all three users, as the registration fields will be different

Comment: It doesn't matter, you simply have to store in the session which type of user is currently logged and then use that information to allow / deny the pages you want.

Comment: basically what you want is to have two users be logged at the same time on the same browser, right?

Comment: @arilia you got it, i want that.

Comment: @Holt basically authorize just decides what actions you are authorized to access and what you can't, Authorize works in conjunction with Auth component, Authorization happens after Auth component logs you in, if i have to go by your approach then all types of users would be able to successfully log in ie Auth Component will successfully create a session . but i dont want this to happen,

Comment: @Holt if i am loged in at mydomain.com/administrator with admin user then i should still be able to see my mydomain.com/public_login not logged as this is the area for my customers. You can just check magento (CMS) where when you are logged in as admin, you are not logged in as customer.

Comment: @FaizAkhtar So basically you want 3 completely separate applications? So just go for it, I don't see why you'd want to put everything in one appication if there is no link between the 3 parts except the database...

Comment: @Holt thanks, one more thing what if i have to built something similar to magento, should i go for two separate applications, one for login, managing customer account on public website and another for login, doing the crud , like adding products using admin panel. What you suggest ?